# Keeping track of on off state of clicked function javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, variables

I know there must be a more efficient way of doing this, I've done it this way in the past because I haven't had many buttons to track, but I now have about 40 buttons that each update updates a mysql table with either a yes or no, and having 40 individual variables and equivalent if statements seems like bad code.

Something to note is that you can see the function has a 1 e.g. *onclick='btnChange(1, this.value);*. There are 7 different buttons, and then these 7 buttons repeat for *onclick='btnChange(**2**, this.value);*. So one solution I thought of is to have 7 if statements for each button and have variable names for each if statement and then I would only have to declare a lot of variables. SO I wasn't sure if that was the best way either. Does this make sense?

```
HTML
<button type="button" name='foo' value="bar1" onclick='btnChange(1, this.value); return false' class='form-control'>Button1</button>

<button type="button" name='hoo' value="bar2" onclick='btnChange(1, this.value); return false' class='form-control'>Button1</button>

JS

var button1YN = 0;
var button2YN = 0;
and so on...

var YNState;

function btnChange(tableid, btnID) {  

  if (btnID == "bar1") {

    if (button1YN === 0) {
      YNState = "yes";
      button1YN = 1;
    } else {
      YNState = "no";
      buttonY1N = 0;
    }
  }
  if (btnID == "bar2") {
    
        if (button2YN === 0) {
          YNState = "yes";
          button2YN = 1;
        } else {
          YNState = "no";
          buttonY2N = 0;
        }
      }

//ajax code to update the mysql table

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a separate variable for each item, create a single variable to represent the state you're attempting to keep track of. This could be an object or an array, depending on your specific needs and/or preferences.

So you might have a state variable that looks like this for example:

```js
// object mapping table names to on/off state
const state = {
  tbl1: true,
  tbl2: false,
  tbl3: true
}
```

or an array:

```js
const state = [true, false, true];
```

If you needed something more complex than true or false (on/off) you could use an array of objects:

```js
const state = [
  {
    table: 't1',
    on: true,
    lastModified: '2021-03-23',
    someOtherThing: 'foo'
  },
  {
    table: 't2',
    on: false,
    lastModified: '2021-03-23',
    someOtherThing: 'bananas'
  },
]
```

Then you just need a function to update the state when something changes. For the simplest case, the true/false array, it could take the index of the item and the new value:

```js
function updateItem(index, newValue) {
  state[index] = newValue;
}
```

Or just toggle the existing true/false value at the given index:

```js
const toggleItem = index => state[index] = !state[index];
```

Then just call that from your button click handler.

Here's a quick proof of concept:

```js
// initial state. 7 buttons, all off (no value)
const buttons = Array.from({length: 7});

// function to flip the state at the given index
const toggleButton = index => {
  buttons[index] = !buttons[index]; // negate existing value. true becomes false, vice-versa
  update(); // redraw the dom
}

// redraws the html.
const update = () => {
  const container = document.querySelector('.demo');
  
  // just spitting out a button for each item in the array.
  // the key thing here is the click handler, which you might
  // want to register differently, but this works for
  // demonstration purposes.
  container.innerHTML = buttons.map((value, index) => `
    <button onclick="toggleButton(${index})">
              ${value ? "✅" : ""} Button ${index}
    </button>
  `).join('');
}

// do the initial draw
update();
```

```css
/* purely cosmetic. irrelevant to functionality */
.demo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100px;
}

button {
  border: none;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo" />
```

Comment: ah thank you. The variable array is what I discovered, but you have a much more involved solution which I'll dig into.

Comment: Don't take the way I'm updating the DOM too seriously. It's pretty inefficient and I just hacked it together for the demo to display the state updates. You might also consider attaching a single click handler to a containing element instead of registering it on each button. You can figure out which button was clicked by inspecting `event.target`.